# Change layout of main and subcategories

Tags: category, layout, magento2.4.0

I'm aware that I can change the layout of a specific category by creating a layout file with the name `catalog_category_view_id_123.xml` where `123` is my category id.

How do I apply a layout change to the parent category (e.g. "Car Parts" with the id "123") and all sub-categories (and sub-sub and sub-sub-sub etc)?

What I'm attempting to do is load one block on a bulk of categories, and a different block on a bulk of different categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can work in products.phtml file in

vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/category/products.phtml

Simply put condition if category has subcategories based on your requirement.

You can change whole layout but you can set structure as per your need